# Python webserver that reads/writes data to/from another python app

Tags: flask, tornado, pyside, qthread, qt-signals

**I would like to** add a simple webserver to my existing python app. 
This webserver should be able to read/write data of my existing app.
I am looking for an easy solution, that only runs in my private local network.

**My existing python app** is based on a QT QTimer object (using PySide) that runs a state machine.
The state machine itself runs lots of other functions. Some functions are event driven and i use several QT signal/slot connections.

**In general the new webserver should:**

- deliver a static website
- send and receive some data to/from the client (Webbrowser) via Ajax. The data consists of settings from my existing python app.

**Whenever the clients sends a request, the webserver should:**

- read data from my existing python app
- send this data back to the client

---

### QUESTIONS

My idea was to use flask as webframework and tornado as webserver. 
I would run flask/tornado in a QThread. 
The data exchange with my existing app could be done by QT signals & slots, since it is easy to handle.

I tried around, but i couldn't figure out, how exactely to run flask/tornado in the thread and use signals & slots at the same time.

- I created a workerclass and pushed it to a qthread via moveToThread(mythread)
- The webserver is started when the signal mythread.started is emitted:

  ```
  def processs(self):
    print ("thread started with id:       " + str(QThread.currentThreadId()))
    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(self.app))
    http_server.listen(5000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
  ```
- A simple route for testing is the following. **Here i would have to send a signal to my existing python app and receive the data via a slot.** But i don't understand how.

  ```
  @app.route('/_add_numbers')    
  def add_numbers():
    """Add two numbers server side, ridiculous but well..."""
    a = request.args.get('a', 0, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 0, type=int)
    return jsonify(result=a + b)
  ```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Nik